# Confusion in Reducibility

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

In Sipser's Theory of Computation book, it is stated while reducing A<sub>TM</sub> to REGULAR<sub>TM</sub>

> We let R be a TM that decides REGULAR<sub>TM</sub> and construct TM S to
>   decide A<sub>TM</sub>. Then S works in the following manner.

S = “On input , where M is a TM and w is a string:

1. Construct the following TM M<sub>2</sub>.

   M<sub>2</sub> = “On input x:

   1. If x has the form 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>, accept .
   2. If x does not have this form, run M on input w and
      accept if M accepts w.”
2. Run R on input < M<sub>2</sub>>
3. If R accepts, accept ; if R rejects, reject .”`

My question is, shouldn't M<sub>2</sub> reject x of the form 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>?

Comment: No.  Here's a hint.  Try to work out the language of $M_2$ in terms of what $M$ does on $w$.  (Also, it might help to think about what other languages could replace $0^n1^n$.)

Comment: @Louis Umm okay, I understand that if M does not accept w, then check if x in M2 is of non-regular form, and then accept OR if M accepts w then simulate and return the result.
What I don't understand is why do we have to return __accept__ when x is of the form 0n1n?

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab: "then check if x in M2 is of non-regular form".  No this isn't what happens.  You need to think about the *language* of $M_2$, since $R$ decides something about the language of $M_2$, not what $M_2$ does on $x$.

Comment: Oh! That's a pretty exact point! Thanks Louis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, M<sub>2</sub> hasn't been designed to accept Regular Languages. It has been designed to be used as argument of R. As per assumption that R can decide REGULAR<sub>TM</sub>, R is free to reject M<sub>2</sub> if the case arises. Remember, decidability includes both acceptance and rejection.

**Update:**
As per definition, R will accept only if argument TM accepts regular language. And, it will reject if argument TM accepts non-regular language. The setup of M<sub>2</sub> harnesses this rejection property of R. If R hasn't rejected (as it can decide, it'll accept), it means point 2 of M<sub>2</sub> was in action (which makes M accept w creating contradiction).

Comment: But why do we return __accept__ when x is of the form 0n1n? That is only the confusion?

Comment: @Abdussami That just ensures that the Turning Machine is more general.

Comment: Kindly elaborate 'general'.
It must reject so the TM rejects. No?

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab The whole point is: If R really exists and it has accepted on M2 argument, it means point 2 of M2 specification is on action and M has accepted w. Point 1 is for otherwise thing.

Comment: R decides this: Can M2 accept Regular Languages? R can say No only when M2 says Yes for non-regular language.

Comment: Sorry for not getting you, but doesn't R stays yes, referring to the accept part in the assumption.

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab R can only accept if it's argument TM accept regular language. If argument TM accepts non-regular language, R rejects as per definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14696/discussion-between-abdussami-tayyab-and-sachin-shekhar).